# How to set new-mailuser as password never expired

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

In my project, I need Exchange Online Powershell to create an Exchange Service Account.
Here is the code sample:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'admin@bdtest.onmicrosoft.com', $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String '123456' -AsPlainText -Force)
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session
Enable-OrganizationCustomization 
$exists=Get-MailUser -Identity 'test1' 
if ($exists) {{  
    remove-mailuser -Identity 'test1' -confirm:$false
}}
New-MailUser -Name 'test1' -DisplayName 'test' -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID  'test1@bdtest.onmicrosoft.com' -Password $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String '123456' -AsPlainText -Force)
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role 'ApplicationImpersonation' -User 'test1'
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role 'Mailbox Search' -User 'test1' 
Remove-PSSession $session
```

what I want to know is:
when the password is expired ?
How I can set it as never expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting password to never expire is not possible using Exchange Online cmdlets, you have to use Office365 cmdlets(and therefore MSOnline module, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx).

Add this to the bottom of your script:

```powershell
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
Get-MSOLUser -SearchString test1 | Set-MsolUser -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this method. However What I want to know is that there exists a method to set it by Exchange Online Powershell not MSOnline Module.

Comment: As per my answer - it is _not_ possible using Exchange Online cmdlets.